# Sync to remote diff by content stuck on loading

Tags: phpstorm

I've been trying to make a switch from Sublime Text 3 with SFTP package to PhpStorm. I'm having a big issue with syncing my local repo with remote server. Sublime allowed me to do that nearly flawlessly with just one press of a button. In PhpStorm however when I try to sync with remote and set to diff by file content, the diff window gets stuck on scanning (loading the files) after a while. If I remove the remote folder it takes so long to load, it just gets stuck on another one. Would greatly appreciate any advice!

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Were you able to find the solution?

Comment: Yes, it turned out it wasn't actually stuck - it was just the GUI. Google around for how to turn logging on, you can then monitor detailed progress in terminal. Unfortunately I wasn't able to speed things up, so my advice to lower the sync time is to take the time and simply exclude all paths that don't change often.

Comment: thank you very much. In case someone needs, [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs) is the link where its explained how you can turn on the logging.

Comment: Did something have changed? When I see trough my logs I can see that the file and folder already got indexed. So waiting and seeing a almost outtimed result and waiting some minutes until the real results shows up becomes really annoying.
 
@zephi: What do you mean with `lower the sync time`?

Comment: Well, in my case I was indexing and syncing a lot of unnecessary stuff. If you exclude the paths you don't need on remote, intellij won't try to compare and sync them, that's all.